# Spotify api for quiz app and written permissions

Tags: api, permissions

I want to use your API for my application, the "Developer Terms of Service" says that I should get written permission, but the mail is not specified anywhere. Where can i get it?

Comment: It's not StackOverflow's API, it's Spotify's. You'll have to ask them. Maybe try their contact page. https://support.spotify.com/us/article/how-can-i-contact-spotify/?in_footer

Answer (score 0):

The following link below, under "App Integration Application" you have to first setup the application. While setting up the application, there is a selection on whether it is a non-commercial or commercial application. By clicking on commercial, there will be the form you are looking for!

https://developer.spotify.com/support/

You can begin setting up your application through this link:

https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/

And welcome to the SO community!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my application is planned as non-commercial, without ads and without in-game purchases, do I still need to arrange it as a commercial one to get permission?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are going to be handling the application after you create it, but as mentioned before, as soon as you setup your application you can use the Spotify's API however you like

Comment: The agreement states the following: Games and trivia quizzes. Unless you receive Spotify’s written approval, you shall not use the Spotify Platform to incorporate Spotify Content into any game functionality (including trivia quizzes).
From here I understand that I must get written approval before using